# Keep selection after assigning new ItemsSource in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

Keep selection after assigning new ItemsSource in ListView? I save ListView.SelectedItems into temporary variable (call it tmp), assign new ItemsSource and then iterate each tmp element and add it to SelectedItems but it doesn't work as expected.

```
var oldSelected = listView.SelectedItems;
listView.ItemsSource = Controller.Automats;
foreach(var item in oldSelected)
{
   listView.SelectedItems.Add(item)
}
```

Unfortunately selection after refreshing is clear always.

Answer (score 1):

Selected items *must* exist in the collection, so saving the items from the previous collection will not help you to select the different items from the new collection. To be clear, I'm talking about the actual items in memory.

What you can do if your items have some kind of identifiable property is to iterate through your saved selected items and add the relevant items from the new collection into the `ListView.SelectedItems` collection using `LinQ`:

```
foreach(var item in oldSelected)
{
    listView.SelectedItems.Add(listView.Items.Single(i => i.Id == item.Id))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have at least two problems here.
First, your `oldSelected` is a **reference** to `SelectedItems` collection, not a separate collection. So when SelectedItems is cleared on `ItemSource` change, then `oldSelected` is cleared too. We can fix it by creating separate list:

```
var oldSelected = listView.SelectedItems.OfType<AutomatOrWhatever>().ToList();
```

Next, even if we have a list of items, new `ItemsSource` most probably has a list of different entities (properties may be the same, but the instance itself is different). To be selected, object must be present in ItemsSource and SelectedItems collections, and your `oldSelected` objects are no longer in ItemsSource, so even if you add them to selection nothing will happen. We need a way to find same items, for example by using one of the properties:

```
var selectedNames = oldSelected.Select(i => i.Name);
foreach (var s in listView.Items.OfType<AutomatOrWhatever>().Where(i => selectedNames.Contains(i.Name)))
{
    lbMain.SelectedItems.Add(s);
}
```

That's just a raw example, but you can get the idea.